# How does adapter deal with empty arrayList in android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i have this code :

WordAdapter.java

```
  public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word>  {

        public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int colorResourceId) {
            super(context, 0, words);
            mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if (listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            Word currentWord = getItem(position);


            TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);

  miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslationId());


            TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);

            defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslationId());


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            if (currentWord.hasImage()) {
                // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
                imageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());
                // Make sure the view is visible
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // Otherwise hide the ImageView (set visibility to GONE)
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            // Set the theme color for the list item
            View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
            // Find the color that the resource ID maps to
            int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
            // Set the background color of the text container View
            textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

            // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews) so that it can be shown in
            // the ListView.
            return listItemView;
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(getActivity(),  new ArrayList<Word>(), R.color.category_phrases);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

i pass empty `ArrayList<Word>` to `WordAdapter` and i run my app, the app shows me a white screen (empty list).   Why does the app not crash when  trying to call `getView()` method  in adapter with no data?   How is the adapter dealing with this case when the array list is empty??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's quite simple

`getView()` is only called when the `count` method returns a value lager than 0

Meaning when you add an empty `ArrayList`, your `count` is `0` so no call to `getView()` is made

Comment: where i can found this method that check if arraylist empty or not?

Comment: what do you mean? The adapter itself checks if the count is larger than 0

Comment: i need to know if there is method doing this operation in the api documentation ?

Comment: You only need to implement the `getCount()` method, not sure what you're trying to achieve. `ArrayList` has `isEmpty()` method

Comment: thanks you give what i need ,getCount() method called in another method  isEmpty() and this  decide to call getView() or not ,